# Responsive menu hidden by main content

Tags: css

I've integrated this simple horizontal menu in all my pages of my web app.

https://jsfiddle.net/3u6m4b1w/

When the page is opened on full screen, all is ok (see pic):

[image]

But when I switch to responsive (see pic 2) I get this strange problem:

The alert box in yellow become bigger in tall, and the menu is hidden behind the main content!

I've already tried with z-index like:

```
.nav-list-pagina { z-index:9999; }
```

but nothing appened.

[image]

What I like to obtain is this (photoshop edited):

[image]

Anyone can help me find the correct CSS?

UPDATED FIDDLE WITH LAST JQUERY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, should work for overlapping.

```
.nav-list-pagina {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Hi @MilosMarkoni, it works well. I'll try to check on all pages

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can add `clear: both;` CSS property to the `.alert` class :

```
.alert {
    position: relative;
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    clear: both;
}
```

[image]

Comment: HI @wlarcheveque it works...but my alert box is not present in all pages... some page start with alert div, or <section> or <fieldset> .... i'd like to edit CSS for menu to ensure get working all my pages

Comment: In this case, I would add a <div> container with the rest of your content and put the alert box into it. I suppose having the menu over the rest of the content would remaina  better practice.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle for tests but I wanted to make a copy. In all cases I found a solution. Let me know if it fits your needs.

Comment: Hi, i don't find your jsfiddle link